# getline() with delim not working as intended

Tags: c++, console-application, getline, split

I'm trying to split this a string with a comma as a delimeter. I put a string "Smith,Erdos,William" and it just outputs "William" but not Smith and Erdos. There must be something wrong here that I just can't see, can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int numScenarios(0);
    int numPapers(0);
    int numWriters(0);
    std::vector<std::string> paperTitles (1);
    std::vector<std::string> paperAuthors (1);
    std::vector<std::string> splitAuthors (1);
    std::string token;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> numScenarios;
    std::cin >> numPapers >> numWriters; 
    for (int i(0); i < numPapers; ++i) {
        std::getline(std::cin,input);
        std::istringstream iss(input);
        while(getline(iss,token,','));
        {
            std::cout << token << std::endl;
        }
        //paperTitles.push_back(input);
        //input = '\0';
    }
    for (int i(0); i < numWriters; ++i) {
        getline(std::cin,input);
        paperAuthors.push_back(input);
        input = '\0';
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Found this (which is an issue you don't address) in the related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039918/stdgetline-does-not-work-inside-a-for-loop?rq=1

Comment: You also seem to push things onto the back of your vectors, but never use the one you put in there during creation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`while(getline(iss,token,',')); // <== look closely`

Comment: `-Wempty-body` (included with `-Wextra`) is your friend.

Comment: Although on second read, `-Wempty-body` only warns for empty bodies in `if`, `else`, and `do...while` statements, *not* `for` or regular `while` statements, so it actually wouldn't help here.