# Calling functions from 'if' and 'switch' statements

Tags: c++

I am building a program that asks for user input and then calls the appropriate function based on which option the user chose. main() is supposed to call fourCode() which has two `do-while` loops in a row. When main() calls fourCode(), it completely skips:

```
 std::cin.getline(message, 499);
```

When the code in fourCode() is moved into main() or is called directly from main(), it works perfectly, but it doesn't work in a separate function when called by the switch or if-else statements. Why is this?

I have spent months on this project and hours of research, in tutorials, books, and the Internet in general. I also showed it to a friend of mine that has been programming for more than five years in several different languages and he said it should work, though he is a little out of practice. I have run out of ideas.

```
 #include <iostream>

 void nullCreator(char, int);
 void convert(int, int, char, char);
 char charDisplay(int, char);
 void fourCode(void);
 void otherCode(void);

 int main()
 {
     char code;
     std::cout << "Please select the code you wish to work with.";
     std::cout << "Press a for a, b for b, etc.\na - 4x4 Code";
     std::cout << "\nb - other Code\n";
     std::cin >> code;
     std::cout << "Option selected: ";
     switch (code)
     {
         case 'a':
             std::cout << "a";
             fourCode();
             break;
         case 'b':
             std::cout << "b";
             otherCode();
             break;
         default:
             std::cout << "none\nThat is an invalide option. ";
             std::cout << "You will have to restart the program.\n";
     }
     return 0;
 }

 void fourCode(void)//main 4x4 code function
 {
     // a few other variables declared
     std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter a message.\n\n";
     std::cin.getline(message, 499);
     std::cout << "\n\n";
     do
     {
         // code here
     } while (character < 500);
     newChar = 0;
     do
     {
         // code here
     } while (newChar < 500);
 }
```

EDIT: (4 months later) I still don't know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: The pitfalls of mixing operator>> and std::getline() strike again... Do not use operator>> to read a single line of input. Always use std::getline(). In fact, forget that operator>> exists. Put it out of your mind. It was just a figment of your imagination. P.S. There's nothing wrong with your switch statement.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039918/stdgetline-does-not-work-inside-a-for-loop/2040012#2040012   (Don't read too much into the question title - neither your problem nor the problem in this question is anything to do with `if`, `for`, or `switch`).

Comment: I tried to implement std::getline(code), but it said there was no matching function for getline(char&). Am I missing something in the syntax?

Comment: Yes. The arguments to std::getline() are a std::string, not a char. Which you already knew, because you already used it, correctly, elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use getline() in main() before the switch statement? As for the arguments, I'm thinking you're saying that I have to put something into getline(code) for proper syntax. If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are mixing styles of input ... in your case `cin >> ...` followed by `cin.getline()`.

A stream's `operator>>()` generally stops when it encounters a pending newline (`'\n'`) and leaves that newline in the stream buffer to be read by a subsequent operation.

`getline()` stops when it encounters a newline, removes the newline from the stream, and returns immediately.

So, if the first character to be read is a newline, `operator>>()` to read a character, followed by `getline()`, will immediately return from both.

To solve the problem, don't mix styles of input on any stream (no problems with using different styles of input on different streams).   Use formatted stream operators (`cin >> ...`) always, or use line oriented input (e.g. `cin.getline()`) always, or character-oriented input (e.g. `cin.get()`) always.     But don't use one then the other on the same stream, because the interaction between them can produce unwanted effects.

If you've spent months looking for a solution to this, you haven't looked hard enough.   There are numerous examples and explanations of this type of thing readily available on the internet.   And I guess (sigh!) I've just added one more.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just wondering one thing; why did the function work when it was called directly from `main()`, but not from within `if-else` or `switch` statements? Just curious.

Comment: Probably because that change affected the sequence of operations.   For example, caused two or three `cin << ...` (which would behave consistently with each other) and then a `cin.getline()` to throw things out of whack.